# Using strtok_r() to Extract Multiple Strings from an Array

Tags: c, unix, strtok

I am trying to parse and simultaneously store some data using strtok_r() from a char array that gets passed into my function. The extraction of the first variable works as expected, when I get to the second I get only a partial portion that occurs between the token and the NULL terminator of the string.
Here I am trying to get the value after 'to=', the password after 'paw=' and the number after the 'tz='. The first and last work, but I am losing tokens on either side of 'paw' and can't seem to extract the text on the other side of the '='. I'm left with NULL every time.

Is this the best way to go about parsing a string like this? I have a working version using strtok() but it uses so many variables because I have to basically store a temp every time and then run tokens on each of them - it is requiring two separate cases, and I would prefer everything to be handled inside one case. I also attempted using strchr() but this was also very cumbersome and required a lot of temporary variables.

Thanks for any advice and I look forward to the discussion!

Here's my code below, it compiles (requires string.h)

```
 int main(int argc, char **argv){    
   char resp[] = "INCOMING,1,443:GET /send?to=12&paw=password&tz=3 HTTP/1.1";

   char *arg;
   char *p_arg;
   char *temp;
   char *p_temp;

   printf("resp is: %s\n",resp); //full response
   arg = strtok_r(resp, ",", &p_arg);
   arg = strtok_r(NULL, ",", &p_arg);
   printf("first num = %s\n", arg); //get the first number
   strtok_r(NULL,"/", &p_arg); //discard the rest up until '/'
   arg = strtok_r(NULL,"?", &p_arg);
   printf("arg is now: %s\n", arg); //we got the first operator "test"

   if(strncmp(arg, "send", 4) == 0){
     while(arg){
       if(strncmp(arg,"to",2) == 0){
          printf("in to, arg is %s\n", arg);
          temp = strtok_r(arg,"to", &p_temp);
          temp = strtok_r(temp,"=", &p_temp); //get the number after 'to='
          printf("to is %s\n", temp);
       } else if(strncmp(arg,"paw",3) == 0){
          printf("In paw, arg is %s\n",arg); //got the paw token
          //now get the password after the '='
          temp = strtok_r(arg,"paw", &p_temp);
          temp = strtok_r(temp,"=", &p_temp);
          printf("paw is %s\n", temp);
       } else if(strncmp(arg,"tz",2) == 0){
          printf("In tz, arg is %s\n",arg); //got the tz token
          temp = strtok_r(arg,"tz=", &p_temp);
          temp = strtok_r(temp," ", &p_temp); //extract tz value
          printf("tz is %s\n", temp);
       }
       arg = strtok_r(NULL,"&", &p_arg);
     } //while
   } //if "test"
 } //main
```

Comment: Theoretically we can find spaces after "12", "password"? Or after "=" or after "to"?

Comment: What do you mean by spaces? In memory, I thought the token turns the wildcard char* into NULL (0x00). In this case, on either end. So that the storage at the pointer location is "\0paw=password\0"

Comment: I mean symbol ' ' (0x20) in resp in general case.

Comment: And yes, better solution is to use strstr().